# How do I match HMACSHA1 from C# to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, hash, hmacsha1

A hashing algorithm in C# needs an exact match in javascript. Because of the logging, I can see that the bytes for the key, and the bytes for the password are the same, but the outputs are different.

What is different between the C# `HMACSHA1` code and the javascript `crypto.createHmac` code that makes it give a different answer? How do I fix the javascript code so that it matches C#?

The C# code (I can't change this) looks like this:

```
private static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
    byte[] keyBytes = HexToByte(SECRET_KEY);
    hash.Key = keyBytes;
    Byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(keyBytes));
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(passwordBytes));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(passwordBytes));
}
```

To match this, I created a function using the crypto module in node.

```
var hash_password = function(password) {
    var keyBytes = Buffer.alloc(SECRET_KEY.length/2, SECRET_KEY, 'hex');
    console.log(toHexString(Uint8Array.from(keyBytes)));
    var hasher = crypto.createHmac("sha1", keyBytes);
    var passwordBytes = stringToBytes16(password);
    console.log(passwordBytes);
    return hasher.update(passwordBytes).digest("Base64");
}
```

I even tried removing the javascript logging in case that was changing anything, but the output was the same either way.

Edit: keyBytes is not a string. In C#, it's a byte array, and in javascript its a Buffer. As far as I know, the important thing is that they contain the same bytes.

javascript: `<Buffer 68 00 75 00 6e 00 74 00 65 00 72 00 32 00 0a 00>`

C#: `68-00-75-00-6E-00-74-00-65-00-72-00-32-00`

Pastebin for [stringToBytes16](https://pastebin.com/XMX48sit) and [toHexString](https://pastebin.com/nbZgs8ef).

Comment: Post all methods used, in particular `stringToBytes16`.

Comment: You're not converting passwordBytes to hex when logging, so I can't see how they'd print the same thing.

Comment: @Topago stringToBytes16 is a function that converts text to a utf16 byte buffer. I know UTF 16 is weird, but I had to write the javascript to match the C# code. (eg. hunter2 -> 68-00-75-00-6E-00-74-00-65-00-72-00-32-00). [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/XMX48sit)

Comment: @Topago toHexString is a function for printing out a byte array. Now that you mention it, if this was off, the whole thing would be messed up. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/nbZgs8ef)

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Both codes produce the same output if the password and key are identical. It is best to post a test case (key, password, results of both codes) for direct comparison. By the way, in the C# byte sequence the last two bytes seem to be missing.

Comment: @Topaco HOLY COW, THAT'S IT! One of them has an extra hidden character! Post this as an answer, and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the answer is in the above notes, but it took me a while to find it and no one actually posted it.  So, here is the working function that produces the same results `HMACSHA1` call from .net all the way back to its start.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function hashPasswordSha1(password: string, membershipKey: string) {
  
  const hashPassword = function(password:any) {
    function stringToBytes16(str:any) {
      let bytesv2:any = []; // char codes
      for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        const code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        bytesv2 = bytesv2.concat([code & 0xff, code / 256 >>> 0]);
      }
      return Buffer.from(bytesv2);
    }
    const keyBytes = Buffer.alloc(membershipKey.length/2, membershipKey, 'hex');
    const hasher = crypto.createHmac("sha1", keyBytes);
    const passwordBytes = stringToBytes16(password);
    return hasher.update(passwordBytes).digest("base64");
  }

  return hashPassword(password);
}
```